# Read multiple sensors from an Arduino

Tags: sensor, arduino

I'm trying to make a system that can take multiple sensor inputs from an Arduino connected through USB to a Raspberry Pi.

Is it possible to differentiate the different sensor inputs on the Pi so `Serial.readline()` can still be used? If not how else can I read the inputs on the Pi?

Answer (score 2):

That is completely under your control.

Personally I would start each sensor message from the Arduino to the Pi with an identifier identifying the sensor.

Comment: So lets say i need all of the inputs at the same time, is there another way to differentiate it?